# Enable Gzip compression in Dropwizard

Tags: java, rest, maven, gzip, dropwizard

i have a REST service , I am using dropwizard 0.6.2.

The pom code is as follow

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yammer.dropwizard</groupId>
        <artifactId>dropwizard-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using a config.yml file.
The code is as follows to start the service

```
new BrAnalyticsNoSQLControllerService().run(new String[] { "server","src\\main\\java\\config.yml"});
```

as per the dropwizard documentation i tried to add following code in config.yml to enable gzip

```
gzip:
  enabled: true
  minimumEntitySize: 256B
  bufferSize: 8KB
```

But I am getting following error when i try to run my service,

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "gzip" (class com.Breezom.BrAnalyticsNoSQLController.REST.Config.BrAnalyticsNoSQLController), not marked as ignorable (7 known properties: , "mongodb", "mongoport", "loggingConfiguration", "http", "mongohost", "httpConfiguration", "logging"])
>    at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: com.Breezom.BrAnalyticsNoSQLController.REST.Config.BrAnalyticsNoSQLController["gzip"])
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:79)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportUnknownProperty(DeserializationContext.java:579)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:672)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializerBase.java:906)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:328)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:121)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2765)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1478)
>       at com.yammer.dropwizard.config.ConfigurationFactory.build(ConfigurationFactory.java:63)
>       at com.yammer.dropwizard.config.ConfigurationFactory.build(ConfigurationFactory.java:48)
>       at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.parseConfiguration(ConfiguredCommand.java:83)
>       at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:51)
>       at com.yammer.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:53)
>       at com.yammer.dropwizard.Service.run(Service.java:61)
>       at com.Breezom.BrAnalyticsNoSQLController.REST.Service.BrAnalyticsNoSQLControllerService.main(BrAnalyticsNoSQLControllerService.java:162)

I am unable to figure out what the problem is.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing your YAML to include the `http:` section like this:

```
http:
  gzip:
    enabled: true
    minimumEntitySize: 256B
    bufferSize: 8KB
```

Comment: as of version 8.1 you need to put this under server instead of http